# Proper Code First EF6 structure for related classes/tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a two classes. A person class and a Title class.

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int TitleTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class TitleType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The title class contains things like "Mr., Mrs., MS.,etc.."

What is the proper way to define these classes so that I can use Linq to recall the desired title "name" from the TitleType table?

i.e. person.Title.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public TitleType Title { get; set; }
}
```

EF will create additional column to handle Foreign Key for you automatically.