# Proper Code First EF6 structure for related classes/tables (one to many)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following classes

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public string State{get; set;} 
}
```

My question is similar to [this previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790037/proper-code-first-ef6-structure-for-related-classes-tables) Except that instead of their being one value in the related table there can be multiple records in the related table.  How can I get the values from the address table.

```
i.e. Contact.Address[0].City
```

Comment: Isn't this an ordinary one to many association? Except that `Icollection` doesn't have an indexer, but you can use `ElementAt()` when the object is in memory (not in an EF query).

Comment: I used the indexer as pseudo code in this case.

Comment: When I use the debugger to see what's in the entity the Address piece is always empty even though there is a table with correct data in it.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().City;
```

Your model is incomplete. You have to reference `Person` in `Address`:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did you mean to have type of address in the address class?

Comment: Fixed it. Typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the model, one way to access the `Address` (via the `Person`) would be to define the relationship. Assuming there is some form of data access, consider changing the definition of Addresses as follows.

```
public virtual List<Address> Addresses {get;set;} // implementing the collection of addresses
public int AddressId {get;set;} // this is the foreign key
```

You can then access the list of addresses like so...

```
 //YourDbContext is System.Data.Entity.DbContext
 List<Address> listOfAddresses = (from listOfPersons in YourDbContext.Persons.Include(listOPersons.Addresses)
 .Where(p=>p.Id==ParameterValue).FirstOrDefault()).Addresses;
 string city = listOfAddresses[0].City;
```